# Solve $y' =\frac 1{3x+\sin(3y)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**Problem**

Solve $y' = \frac 1{3x+\sin(3y)}$

**Progress**

Sadly none. Any help/tips/solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1427071/how-to-solve-this-first-order-differential-equation only a few minutes ago

Comment: Oh, this should be closed, then...

Comment: I don't know why that didnt' show up in my search. Maybe formatting. Anyway... I just threw in a close vote on my own question, so that's a first.

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that you will find a solution written as $y=f(x)$, so we will be happy in finding one in the form $x=f(y)$ instead.

The differential equation can be written
$$
x'(y)=3x(y)+\sin 3y.
$$
This is a linear differential equation of first order. Solving it, using integrating factor, we find that
$$
x(y)=Ce^{3y}-\frac{1}{6}(\cos 3y+\sin3y),
$$
where $C$ is arbitrary.

I leave it to you to try to solve this for $y$ in terms of $x$, but I won't stay up all night waiting for the answer... ;)

Comment: Pardon my inexperience, but why do you figure that a $y(x)$ solution is out of the question?

Comment: Well, one should never say never, but given that the right-hand side involves a sum of an exponential function (with real argument) and trigonometric functions, I think the odds are against us. Also, it is late here...